# Linter Error: Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named fb:page_id.

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We're getting the following error in the debugger after adding the OG tags to our site...

Linter Error:  Extraneous Property: Objects of this type do not allow properties named fb:page_id.

Here's the Linter link...

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sitesell.com%2F

This is for our home page, http://www.sitesell.com/

What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much for your help!

Christian

Answer (score 6):

I think that `fb:page_id` is only used for claiming OG objects of type `website` to use Facebook Insights.

The linter also says that the `og:type` is inferred, not explicitly declared. So perhaps because you have not declared the `og:type` it is not expecting `fb:page_id`?

**On April 1st, 2012 Facebook will be deprecating domain claiming for Facebook Domain Insights using the `fb:page_id` tag.** So you will need to remove this eventually anyway.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/03/28/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

**To claim a page for Insights it's recommended to use the `fb:admins` or `fb:app_id` tags instead:**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/

Comment: Thank you so much, thaddeusmt! That helps tremendously! -Christian

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced such bug too. Check your namespace connections. For example I had two connect head tag:

one (this one i took in tutorial):

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#mynamespace: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/mynamespace#">
```

and next one (this one I took in get code object tool):

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# mynamespace: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/mynamespace#">
```

Then I removed the second one, and problem disappeared.